# unhandled exception while running the program in VC++ 2008

Tags: c

I was trying to open a binary file in the directory and perform the operations accordingly.I doubt this line..is not the correct way of representation to work the below logic.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int k=0;
  FILE *fp;
  unsigned char cd[255];
  unsigned long cd1[500];
  char *buffer;
  unsigned long sa=80044;
  int j=0,i=0,n=0;
  DIR *dir;
  struct dirent *direntry; //could be a file, or a directory

  dir = opendir("C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/vicky");
  if(!dir) {
  printf("Error: directory did not open!\n");
  return 1;
  }

  while((direntry=readdir(dir))!=NULL) {
  if(++k < 100)
  {
     printf("%s\n",direntry->d_name);
     sprintf(buffer,"%s",direntry->d_name);//here i got the unhanded exception.
     fp=fopen("buffer","rb");
     sa=sa-44;
     sa=sa/8;

  if(fp==NULL)
 {
   printf("file not found!");
 }
 else
      {
       for(j=0;j<(sa);j++)
       {
           for(i=0;i<8;i++)
           {
               cd[i]=fgetc(fp);//get each character from file 

              // printf("%c",cd[i]);

           }
           if(i==8)//if the i is 8 the character then do the following,just read 8 bytes  and then calculate the cd1.
           {
                sa=sa-8;
               cd1[j]=(cd[6] * 65536 + cd[5] * 256 + cd[4]);//multiply the positional weightage and calculate the cd1,which contains the 7 digits decimal value.

               //if((cd1[j]> 0x7FFFFF)&&(cd1[j]<=0xFFFFFF))

                 //cd1[j]=cd1[j]- 0xFFFFFF;
                 //cd1[j]=cd1[i] * -1;

           }
         printf("completes first 8 bytes read:%d - %d",j,cd1[j]);//print j and cd1[j] value in console window

       }
      fclose(fp);//close the file
   }


  }
  if((strcmp(direntry->d_name, "text.txt"))==0) {
     printf("\nThe %s file has been found\n",direntry->d_name);

     k=-99;  //just a flag value to show the file was found
     break;
   }

  }
  if(k!=-99)
  printf("\nThe test.txt file was not found\n");

  closedir(dir);

  printf("\n");
  getchar();
  return 0;

 }
```

This is error i got:Unhandled exception at 0x1029a189 (msvcr90d.dll) in READ_TEXT.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xcccccccc.Kindly let me any suggestion to read the "direntry->d_name" file name to process the above logic.

Comment: buffer hasn't been allocated to point to anything

Comment: After you fix the allocation problem, you try to open a file named "buffer". Change the string in the call to `fopen` to be the variable `buffer` not the string `"buffer"`. Also, for it to be successful, you  might need to have the full path to the file in the `buffer` variable`.

Comment: thanks joachim, I am able to read each file in the directory and displaying in console window. after that i am trying to open the file..whcih is not happening here.I changed the buffer as variable.not string.dir varaible contains directory path?.Is there any other way to work this properly?

Comment: You should configure your project to warning level 4 and code analysis on. I am sure MSVC will warn you about using the uninitialized variable buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the character buffer an ordinary array, for simplicity's sake:

```
char buffer[1024];
```

That way you're sure to have the memory put aside and ready to use. You should use `snprintf()` if your platform provides it.

Comment: thanks for the reply...it worked..but used sprintf() itself.MS VC++ 2008 is the compiler am using.

Comment: here am getting file not found! filename in console output. eg:file not found! filename.txt.but not the actual output as expected.why am not able to open the file in that directory and do the other operations...pls any idea.

Answer (score 0):

`buffer` is not allocated. `sprintf()` is basically attempting to write "nowhere".

The destination variable needs to be either allocated on the heap using `malloc` or on the stack restricting its use to the current scope.

Answer (score 0):

You have only declared char* buffer, not allocate memory for it using malloc().

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is an uninitialized pointer.

Initialize the pointer with malloc or try an array

```
char buffer[1024];
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
char * buffer;
```

to

```
char buffer[MAX_PATH];
```

or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

U must allocate the memory for the buffer variable.
char *buffer; statement is not allocating any memory so that i could have 
any data.

so better u try
chat buffer[//buffer length];

or char *buffer = new char(//buffer length);

or char *buffer = (char*)malloc(//buffer length);

these above statement will allocate memory and fix your issue.